# Finding a closed formula for a sum

Tags: summation

I wrote this sum (out of the blue) and wondered if it has a closed form:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} L^{\frac{1}{k}} \cdot(-1)^{k+1}$$ where $L \in \mathbb{N}$

I thought of a sum that would use "$\text{k-root}$" but with alternating sign ($+$ to $-$ etc..)

I couldn't find a way to do so, the only thing I did is write a program that calculates it, so I post here for help.  Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: Does it converge?

Comment: @JackyChong Well in my program I checked values $k = 1,000,000+$ and it seems to converge but I am not sure..

Comment: Have you tried the divergence test?

Comment: Individual terms converge to $1$ not $0$.

Comment: I found that If this sum converged, your partial sums too.$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} L^{\frac{1}{k}} -1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t converge unless $L=0$. For $n\ge 1$ let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^nL^{1/k}(-1)^{k+1}$. If $L\ge 1$, then $L^{1/k}\ge 1$ for all $k\ge 1$, so $|s_{n+1}-s_n|\ge 1$ for all $n\ge 1$. Thus, the sequence of partial sums is not Cauchy and cannot converge.

Comment: Wow nice answer sir! But something is weird, because in my program, it seems to get fixed on a specific number (according to L of course)

Comment: @StackOMeow: I would check the program; for $L=2$ the partial sums for a modest number of terms should appear to oscillate between values not too far from $0.7$ and $1.7$.

Comment: Ohh right! it is indeed, for some even values of $k$ the sum = $c$ and for odd $k$ equals $c+1$ . So will we be able to find a closed form of the partial sums for even / odd $k$'s ? thank you sir!

Comment: @StackOMeow: You’re welcome! I don’t know for sure about the odd and even subsequences, but it wouldn’t surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove its subsequences's convergence but can't find their exact values.
$(L-L^{\frac{1}{2}})+(L^{\frac{1}{3}}-L^{\frac{1}{4}})+...+(L^{\frac{1}{n-1}}-L^{\frac{1}{n}})
=
L+(-L^{\frac{1}{2}}+L^{\frac{1}{3}})+(-L^{\frac{1}{4}}+L^{\frac{1}{5}})+...-L^{\frac{1}{n}}
＜L-1$

$L+(-L^{\frac{1}{2}}+L^{\frac{1}{3}})+(-L^{\frac{1}{4}}+L^{\frac{1}{5}})+...+(-L^{\frac{1}{n-1}}+L^{\frac{1}{n}})
=(L-L^{\frac{1}{2}})+(L^{\frac{1}{3}}-L^{\frac{1}{4}})+...+L^{\frac{1}{n}}
＞1$